# Is "You are too good to be gifted" grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

> "You are too good to be gifted."

Is this a grammatically correct way to respond to someone who is asking for a gift?

Comment: What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: Yes, please elaborate, and explain what it means for someone to be "too good" to be given a gift.

Comment: People who are good are generally those who *do* get gifts. It's people who are bad who don't . . . (So, semantically, it's an odd response. Although, people don't normally *ask* for gifts either.)

Answer (score 2):

Grammatical, sure. But as written, that sentence could be misinterpreted as:

> You are too good to be [talented](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gifted)

(because *gifted*, as an adjective, means "talented").

It could also mean:

> You are too good to be given away as a gift.

---

Instead you should say:

> You are too good to be gifted something

or

> You are too good to be given a gift

Comment: I'm not a big fan of "You are too good to be gifted something." At best, that's an unusual construct. Why not something more like: _You are too good to be given a gift_. That seems to be what the OP is saying.

Comment: *You are too good to be gifted **with** something* is the more idiomatic (although uncommon) use of the verb. Also, the *original* sentence could also be be interpreted as somebody being too good to be given to somebody else ***as*** a gift.

Comment: This is a nice answer but premature since we aren't certain what OP is trying to say.

Comment: @Andrew - Agreed, but I'm hoping the question doesn't get closed. (Closed migrated questions go back to where they came from, and I think this question fits better here than ELU).